# Mandrill send email ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, mandrill

Im using mandrill for sending email and it show for some emails that the email From: `ma@mail133-28.atl131.mandrillapp.com [mailto:ma@mail133-28.atl131.mandrillapp.com]` On Behalf Of `info@****.com`

in my name mailer

```
default from: "info@****.com"
```

and in the development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.mandrillapp.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'www.****.com',
    :user_name => '**@**.ca',
    :password => '***',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
```

Why is that? i want to show from: `info@****.com` without this `ma@mail133-28.atl131.mandrillapp.com [mailto:ma@mail133-28.atl131.mandrillapp.com]` On Behalf Of `info@****.com`

Answer (score 2):

From [Mandrill KB](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582237-How-do-I-get-rid-of-the-on-behalf-of-message-that-shows-for-some-recipients-)

> If your recipients use Outlook, Hotmail (and other Microsoft webmail
>   services), or Gmail, they may see an indication in the email that it
>   was sent by Mandrill on your behalf instead of just your 'from' name
>   and address. Add SPF and DKIM records to your sending domains to
>   remove the 'on behalf of' or 'via' information.

Instructions on how do that can be found here: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582277-How-do-I-add-DNS-records-for-my-sending-domains-